# Can't use C2DM intent (android)

Tags: android, android-c2dm

I try to register to C2DM but it doesn't work. I included com.google.android.c2dm in my project. When I try to find `com.google.android.c2dm.intent.REGISTER` , it doesn't find anything :

```
String action = "com.google.android.c2dm.intent.REGISTER";
final PackageManager packageManager = context.getPackageManager();
final Intent intent = new Intent(action);
List<ResolveInfo> list = packageManager.queryIntentActivities(intent, PackageManager.MATCH_DEFAULT_ONLY);
```

`list.size()` give 0. Any idea?

EDIT : mu manifest file contains the corrects permissions :

```
<uses-permission android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.permission.RECEIVE" />
```

Comment: are you on a 2.1 device?   C2DM works on 2.2 and higher.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to make sure you have the `com.google.android.c2dm.permission.RECEIVE` permission in your manifest file.

Also, I implemented registration using the following boilerplate

```
Intent registrationIntent = new Intent("com.google.android.c2dm.intent.REGISTER");
registrationIntent.putExtra("app", PendingIntent.getBroadcast(this, 0, new Intent(), 0)); 
registrationIntent.putExtra("sender", emailOfSender);
startService(registrationIntent);
```

You can refer to [the full docs](http://code.google.com/intl/sv-SE/android/c2dm/index.html#writing_apps) for basic setup.

Comment: edited question. And I use the same code but of course it triggers the error : SERVICE_NOT_AVAILABLE

Comment: I'm assuming you have signed up c2dm? http://code.google.com/intl/sv-SE/android/c2dm/signup.html  Also google suggests that error mean "The device can't read the response, or there was a 500/503 from the server that can be retried later. The application should use exponential back off and retry."

Comment: Yes I have signed up. I don't know if my registration is active yet but if the problem was my account, I guess I would get an error like AUTHENTICATION_FAILED or INVALID_SENDER